# (Koala) Can't compile variables in Sass

Tags: sass, koala

It's my first time using Koala.
Everything works fine so far, but when I want to use variables it starts giving me errors. I really don't know what I'am doing wrong, cause I followed all steps.

For example:

`$test: #00000;` would give me error (doesn't matter in which .scss file I put it in.

I have uploaded a screenshot of my structure and the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem with the code is that you supplied `5` digits for the value of a `hexadecimal` value.

You should either use `3` or `6` and not `5`

```
$test: #000000; // not #00000
```

The reason why it worked by not importing `_variables.scss` is because it is a ***partial** file* and by not importing it, it never gets **compiled** and so it basically doesn't evaluate the line causing the error. That line is just ignored.